# Linear independence for a sequence vs. a set

Tags: linear-algebra

I am an undergraduate working through 2ed of Kunze's Linear Algebra. I would prefer answers that value sharing more information and clarification over conciseness. Also, I know there is a question on here which is nearly the same as this one. However, I cannot comment on that post and find the answers provided confusing enough to warrant asking the question again. Here's the link to the duplicate: [Regarding linear dependence and independence for finite sequences of vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340844/regarding-linear-dependence-and-independence-for-finite-sequences-of-vectors)

At the very end of the section on basis and dimension, Kunze says:

> Thus, if $\alpha_1,⋯,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent, they are distinct and we may talk about the set $\alpha_1,⋯,\alpha_n$ and know that it has $n$ vectors in it. So, clearly, no confusion will arise in discussing bases and dimension. The dimension of a finite-dimensional space  is the largest n such that some $n$-tuple of vectors in  is linearly independent—and so on. The reader who feels that this paragraph is much ado about nothing might ask [themselves] whether the vectors
> $$\alpha_1 =(e^\frac{\pi}{2},1)$$
> $$\alpha_2 = (\sqrt[3]{110},1)$$
> are linearly independent in $R^2$.

What is the purpose of this paragraph? It seems that the only difference between dealing with a set and a sequence is that it's generally implied there are no duplicate vectors in a set. Thus, one needs to check for duplicate vectors in a sequence because duplicate vectors implies linear dependence. However, this idea seems not useful and very strange to dedicate a page to.

Lastly, I do believe that these two vectors form a linearly independent sequence/set. Is this accurate?

I feel I must be misunderstanding something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the link to the duplicate.

Comment: Added the link to the post!

Comment: Thanks.  I don't really see the point to the paragraph.  Sets have no order to them, and it may be useful to be able to say that the basis $\{\vec u, \vec v\}$ is the same as the basis $\{\vec v, \vec u\}$.  Granted, this point doesn't seem worth a whole paragraph.  And it is entirely obvious that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are linearly independent...not sure what they were thinking there.

Comment: Okay awesome. I wasn't sure if I was just crazy and missing some subtle point.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you are missing anything momentous.

Comment: Consider the linearly independent set $\{u,v\}$. Now I ask you: is the sequence $(u,v)$ linearly independent?

Comment: @jjagmath I would say yes because Kunze's definition of linear (in)dependence takes on the same form whether you're dealing with sets or sequences. At least to my understanding. Thus, I am led to believe that c_1(u) + c_2(v) = 0 only with the trivial solution applies to both scenarios if it applies to one.

Comment: If $u=v\ne 0$ then $\{u,v\} = \{u\}$ is linearly independent. However $(u,u)$ is not.

Comment: Hm. I see. So then is the purpose of the paragraph is to show that it is convention to ignore duplicate elements in a set?

Comment: That specific example seems entirely pointless. I wonder what insight we are intended to collect from it.

Comment: And in the example given, to determine if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are linearly independent you'll have to show that they are different, but $e^{\pi/2}\approx \sqrt[3]{110}$, so it would be difficult without the aid of a calculator.

Comment: Okay! Thank you everyone. This has helped a lot.

Comment: Better read Friedberg, Insel and Spence (FIS) linear algebra as opposed to Kunze's (my school used to use Kunze's back in the early 2000s with very poor results). I was fortunate enough that in 2008 when I took my first course of Linear Algebra, we changed to FIS. Kunze is OK if you already know the contents but it is really obfuscated otherwise.

Comment: @WilliamM. I have just finished my first course in linear and was looking for a text that would be “advanced linear algebra”. Would you still go for Friedberg? I have seen this text, Axler, etc. pop up a lot. However it seems Axler is akin to the Feynman Lectures in which you read them after you already know the content to get a different perspective.

Comment: FIS is very complete, has very consistent notacion and great examples. I never read Axler but I did check Hoffman and Kunze and definitely didn't like it.