# Hoffman and Kunze on the linear independence of a sequence vs. set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

At the end of a long chapter in which they introduce the basic definitions of linear independence, basis, and dimension (Chapter 2.3 of the second edition), Hoffman and Kunze (HK) provide the following discussion where they seem to define linear independence now for $n$-tuples (rather than, as before, for sets).

I'm not sure I "get it" for a couple reasons:

1. I am a reader who "feels this paragraph is much ado about nothing". Can anyone explain why it's something? I'll add that those two vectors which are given are linearly independent, but I don't know what point is trying to be made?
2. It seems like we've shown that linear independence of a sequence implies linear independence of the corresponding set, but linear independence of the set need not imply linear independence of any sequence built therefrom, since we could double up elements of the set in the sequence (the contrapositive, that linear dependence of the sequence need not imply the linear dependence of the set -- in particular when the sequence has repeats -- is what HK were talking about). Is this understanding correct? And, if so, why does that matter?

[image]

Comment: I recommend you feel free to ignore it for now and come back later, maybe even after one chapter.  I think the authors are just being overly precise where other authors are more fast and loose when talking about sets of vectors and sequences of vectors.  I understand the point they are making but it’s fairly abstract and off topic from the new ideas being introduced; come back later and see if it’s helpful.

Comment: I will definitely come back! If you are at all able to supply an answer at the moment I'd love to "give it a try" (and refer back to it in the future if not), but no worries if not. @Callus-ReinstateMonica

Comment: I found this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340844/regarding-linear-dependence-and-independence-for-finite-sequences-of-vectors) which seems to answer why the particular two vector example given by HK might (morally) depend on which definition of l.i. we use, but that is just a matter of "effort" to determine if something is l.i. It's still not clear to me why we need both definitions, and can't just use one or the other definitions.

Comment: Perhaps more modern books will be less confusing (and will also contain less sexist language).

Comment: True on both fronts. But HK is a classic for good (mathematical) reasons, as is discussed at length on this forum. @GregMartin

Comment: And maybe for more formal (though honestly skippable for now) remarks about this sort of thing, see pages 13-14 and the ending of page 72, beginning of page 73 of Loomis and Sternberg for remarks about indexed collections (namely the indexing function vs its image, and the associated common notational ambiguity), and how this relates to the definition of linear independence.

Comment: But really, while there *is* something to be addressed here, if you don’t get it right now, just skip and come back later once you feel like you’re able to handle some more technicalities (because that’s what this is; an important and necessary one, but it’s the kind which you address for yourself once and move on (and there’s no reason to do so ASAP)).

Comment: Wow, my brain is melting after reading those sections of LS. I will have to try again later (or, rather, earlier in the day)! Thanks for the tip. @peek-a-boo

Comment: @peek-a-boo I will read LS again tomorrow, but would you mind taking a quick peek at my comment on the answer below? I wonder if I am on to something regarding the LS index set discussion and this "mapping" between "underlying sets" and lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *almost* much ado about nothing. In linear algebra, when we don't need or care about the ability to denote the same vector twice, or to denote vectors in a particular order, it can be convenient to work with *sets* of vectors. Other times, when we do care about one or both of those things -- like when choosing basis vectors in a certain order for coordinate representations, as the authors do in the next section -- it's more convenient to work with *lists* (sequences, tuples) of vectors.

The issue the authors are trying to highlight is that we need to be careful about *distinctness* of vectors in relation to linear dependence when switching between sets and lists. Consider the definition of linear dependence for sets, paraphrased here (from p.40):

> A set $S$ of vectors is **linearly dependent** if there exist distinct vectors $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ in $S$ and scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ not all zero such that $c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n=0$.

Notice we require distinctness of $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ here. If we didn't, then *any* nonempty set $S$ of vectors would trivially be linearly dependent, because for $\alpha\in S$ we can always take $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha$ and write $1\cdot\alpha_1+(-1)\cdot\alpha_2=0$.

On the other hand, compare this with the corresponding definition for (finite) lists, in which the elements need not be distinct, paraphrased (from p.47):

> The vectors $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are **linearly dependent** if there exist scalars $c_1\ldots,c_n$ not all zero such that $c_1\alpha_1+\cdots+c_n\alpha_n=0$.

At first glance it's tempting to think that a list $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is linearly dependent if and only if its underlying set $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ is, but that's false because of the distinctness issue. More specifically if the underlying set is linearly dependent, then the list is linearly dependent, but the converse is false.

The example they give is meant to illustrate this difference epistemically. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $\alpha_1=(e^{\pi/2},1)$ and $\alpha_2=(\sqrt[3]{110},1)$, then we know that the *set* $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ is linearly independent (that is, not linearly dependent) *even if we don't know whether $e^{\pi/2}=\sqrt[3]{110}$*:

- If $e^{\pi/2}\ne\sqrt[3]{110}$, then the set is linearly independent since $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are not scalar multiples of each other.
- If $e^{\pi/2}=\sqrt[3]{110}$, then $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$, so $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}=\{\alpha_1\}$ is also linearly independent since $\alpha_1\ne0$.

On the other hand to know that the *list* $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is linearly independent, we need to know that $e^{\pi/2}\ne\sqrt[3]{110}$.

Is this a big deal? No. In fact some books which use both sets and lists don't even bother mentioning it, while other books stick primarily to lists to avoid the issue. But it can cause confusion and error for beginners when switching between sets and lists, which is probably why the authors wrote this. However, I suspect what they wrote serves to increase confusion more than decrease it.

Comment: Thank you once again for a very nice, clear, and helpful answer. Per peek-a-boo's comment, I'll probably look at Loomis and Sternberg tomorrow for more insight, but for now I guess the key is your line that "More specifically if the underlying set is linearly dependent, then the list is linearly dependent, but the converse is false."

Comment: I can't quite tell right now, but I suspect some of peek-a-boo's comments about indexing functions may have to do with the mapping between "underlying set" and list which is left vague here. That is, the mapping from list to set may be clear, but the reverse mapping is not (how many "copies" does one include)?

Comment: the reconcile the language, the list $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ referred to here is what LS would call the indexing function $\alpha:\{1,\dots, n\}\to V$, defined such that for each $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$, $\alpha(i):=\alpha_i$. The set $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}\subset V$ is then simply the image of the mapping $\alpha:\{1,\dots, n\}\to V$.

Comment: Sorry @peek-a-boo, just seeing this now cause I don't get notifications for this. To confirm, they would call it that because of the isomorphism between functions on $\alpha:\{1,\dots, n\}$ and ordered $n$-tuples I guess?

Comment: P.S. I just reread LS pages 12-14 on indexing sets and had two quick questions if it's OK: (1) I am a bit baffled by the generalized definition of Cartesian product they give. I mean, I get it, but my problem is that the codomain is ill-defined - there is a different codomain for each $i$! Or should we interpret the codomain as the union over $i$ of each $S_i$? I ask because Amann and Escher (and many others) make codomain a crucial part of a function definition.

Comment: (2) At the top of page 13, where they begin "this kind of ambiguity". What am I to make of this? Are they throwing their hands up and saying that we define anything that has a natural isomporhism between them as the same thing? Thus, for example and using their notation, if $X$ is some set then we say $X^2 = X^{\overline{2}}$?

Comment: @EE18 It would be better to post those as a separate question, not in comments here.

Comment: @blargoner I was just hoping to put it here so that I can refer back to the discussion (I include links to these questions in my notes) given that it had already started, but that makes sense. I'll just add one last question so I don't forget it and then try to figure out how to port things over: (3) In the third last paragraph LS discuss a coordinate function (on $I$) instead of a coordinate $n$-tuple (on $\overline{n}$). But if we are considering a *finite* indexed set, then isn't every such set indexed by some $\overline{n}$? Why would we even need to discuss some finite $I$?

Comment: @EE18 That's what links are for :) This site discourages long, drawn out comment threads.