# How to think about the linear independence of multisets?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have just finished solving the following problem from Chapter 2.3 of Hoffman and Kunze:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a subfield $F$ of the complex numbers. Suppose $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are linearly independent vectors in $V$. Prove that $\alpha + \beta$, $\beta + \gamma$, $\gamma + \alpha$ are linearly independent.

The relevant definitions and characterizations are as follows:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$. A subset $S$ of $V$ is said to be **linearly dependent**  if there exist distinct vectors
> $\alpha_i \in S$ and scalars $c_i$, not all zero, such that
> $$ 0 = \sum_i c_i \alpha_i.$$

A characterization of the negation of the above (which I use in my solution) is the following:

> A set  of vectors is linearly independent if and only if each finite subset of S is linearly independent, i.e., if and only if for any finite set of distinct
> vectors $\alpha_i \in S$ we have that $ 0 = \sum_i c_i \alpha_i$ implies $c_i = 0$ for all $i$.

I emphasize that the repeated appearance of "distinct" here is a source of confusion in what follows.

My solution is as below:

> We use the characterization 4 on page 41 for linear independence. Call the first set $S$ and the latter $S'$. Suppose all three elements of $S$ are distinct (**if not, then...**), so that all of the elements of $S'$ are distinct (if they weren't then we would have two elements of $S'$ equal to each other, say WLOG $\alpha + \beta = \gamma + \beta \implies \alpha = \gamma$, contradicting that $S$ has distinct elements) and fix
> $$0 = c_1(\alpha + \beta)+c_2(\beta + \gamma) + c_3 \gamma + \alpha = (c_1 + c_3)\alpha + (c_1 + c_2)\alpha+ (c_2 + c_3)\gamma.$$
> Then since $S$ is l.i., we must have $c_1 = -c_3 = -(-c_2) = c_2 = -c_1 \implies c_1 = 0 \implies c_2 = c_3 = 0$, so that $S'$ is l.i. too.

I have bolded the part which leads me to my question. What am I to say if $S$ is not made up of distinct vectors (i.e. is a multiset?). It seems that in this very easy case I could potentially go by cases, and say that "if $\alpha = \beta$, then...". But how would I do this in general? The cases method is clearly not tractable. I also feel like I am missing something related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766274/hoffman-and-kunze-on-the-linear-independence-of-a-sequence-vs-set) question. Should I simply agree that we ought not talk about the linear independence of sets, and only talk about the linear independence of sequences?

Comment: If they are not distinct they are not linearly independent (take $a-a=0$) so this does not really matter. Same for the order, it matters only when you give a basis decomposition. The method using the definition works usually well.

Comment: NB the definition I gave though. The definition includes the "distinct" requirement. Thus, according to the definition given, $\{(1,0),(1,0)\}$ is a l.i. sub(multi?)set of $F^2$. @julio_es_sui_glace I know this is all very contrived but per my linked question, this all seems to "matter".

Comment: Ok Yes I see what you mean, this is useful when’s you check linear independance for infinite families/sets, however if you have a finite family $x_1 , \dots , x_n$ you could say they are independent iff $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i = 0 \implies \forall i , \, \lambda_i =0$ so for the finite case with this definition you don’t need to ensure distinctness, but you do if you study an infinite space.

Comment: @EE18: no, both of the definitions you gave only apply to *sets* of vectors, not to multisets. Per your linked question we can also talk about linear dependence and independence of *sequences* of vectors and that requires something very slightly different.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Can you explain how $S$ being infinite matters? I don't follow.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I tend to agree with you, I think. You are saying that *set* means set -- in particular, every element is distinct definitionally (and therefore we can drop any mention of "distinct" from all of HK's definitions here)?

Comment: @EE18: "distinct" can be dropped in the second definition since it says "finite set" but not in the first definition since it, strictly speaking, refers to a sequence $\alpha_i$. As far as I'm concerned this is just sort of an annoying technical detail, I wouldn't read too much into this either way.

Comment: The annoying technical detail has to do again with the distinction between "indexed sets" (i.e. sets which are ranges of some index function) and regular old sets? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @EE18: I would say between sequences and sets. The reason we can safely restrict our attention to sets of vectors here is that everyone understands that two copies of the same vector are linearly dependent.

Comment: Do you have any sense about why we insist on talking about sequences of vectors (as it pertains to bases and independence)? That is, why can't we just simplify our lives and agree (i.e. in all of the relevant *definitions*) that we are only going to talk about sets of vectors (and, by the definition of a set, all elements thereof are distinct and so we don't even need to make mention of distinctness)? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @EE18: it's just convenient to work with sequences of vectors sometimes. E.g. if you have a sequence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can make them the rows or columns of a matrix; if you only had a set of vectors then technically you'd need to pick an order. It also keeps the notation easy, you can write $v_1, v_2, \dots v_k$ and so forth. And various arguments in linear algebra involve constructing sequences of vectors anyway (e.g. Gram-Schmidt, the spectral theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your definition is $S \subset V$ is linearly independent if $\forall X \subset S$, $|X|$ finite,
$$ \sum_{x \in X } \lambda_x x = 0 \implies \forall x \in X, \, \lambda_x = 0 .$$

Using this notation you don't really need to specify the $x$'s are different because it is inherent to the notation. If you consider a subset, summing elements indexed by this set will automatically take different elements at each time.

However if you use your definition, you say for $x_1,\dots , x_m \in S$ **distinct**,
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i x_i = 0 \implies \forall I , \, \lambda_i = 0.$$

What I was saying is that you can be sure to avoid any confusion in the finite case, with the family notation. The family $(x_1,\dots,x_m) \in V^m$ is linearly independent iff
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i x_i = 0 \implies \forall I, \, \lambda_i = 0.$$
In this case, the family $(x,x)$ will not be linearly independent, however with the precedent definition, the set $\{x,x\} = \{x\}$ will be.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. BTW, I think your last equation is missing a 0 on the LHS. At any rate, am I to understand that you're saying that HK's original definition of linearly dependent (the one I gave in OP, at the start) is actually about families (i.e. indexed sets as I mention to Qiaochu Yuan above) rather than sets, even though they says *sets*?

Comment: Yes it was edited. For your interrogation, in many sources it will ambiguously change from set to family to sequence, you'll need to interpret what the most logical fit for your situation (unfortunately). They all mean the same idea, but sometimes it is more fitting to use one and not the others. But I think you got it! :) I'm glad if this helped you don't hesitate to ask for further explanations.