# Problem in understanding the phrase, "Prove that every vector in the span of $S$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of vectors of $S.$"

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ a subset of V with the property that
whenever $v_1, v_2,...,v_n ∈ S$ and $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + ··· + a_nv_n = 0 , $ then $a_1 = a_2 = ··· = a_n = 0.$ Prove that every vector in the span of $S$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of vectors of $S.$

My solution is:

Let $v\in \text{span} (S)$ then, $\exists x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\in S$ and scalars $c_1,...,c_n$ such that $c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n=s.$ Let $b_1,...,b_n$ be scalars such that, $b_1x_1+...+b_nx_n=s$ then, $$c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n=b_1x_1+...+b_nx_n\implies (c_1-b_1)x_1+...+(c_n-b_n)x_n=0\implies c_1-b_1=...=c_n-b_n=0\implies c_1=b_1,c_2=b_2,...,c_n=b_n.$$

This proves the result.

---

However, as one can see, by the phrase, "every vector in the span of $S$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of vectors of $S,$" I assumed that, for a set of vectors the scalars are uniquely determined, but am I misinterpreting the question? Does it mean that say, that if, we have another set of vectors, $y_1,...,y_k$ and $a_1,...,a_k$ such that $$a_1y_1+\cdots +a_ky_k=c_1x_1+...+c_nx_n=s,$$ then, $k=n$ and $a_1=c_1,a_2=c_2,...,a_n=c_n$ and $x_1=y_1,...,y_{k(=n)}=x_n$ ?

To me the question as written sems ambiguous. This is a question from the book, "Linear Algebra " by Friedberg, Insel and Spence from the chapter named, Vector Spaces.

Comment: Yes, it means the scalars are uniquely determined, and no, of course it does not mean that other thing you wrote down which is very false (e.g. we could take $a_1 = 1, y_1 = s$ and all the other vectors and scalars to be zero, and if $s \neq x_1, \dots x_n$ this will be different from the linear combination using the $x_i$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks a ton for clarifying!

Comment: What you say makes no sense whatsoever. You've changed the set $S$. What allowed you to do that? The letter $S$ appears twice in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is unfortunate as written for multiple reasons. It's ambiguous about uniqueness, as you note. Also, under the given hypothesis, $S$ must be *empty*! Indeed, if we had $v\in S$ then we could take $v_1=v_2=v$ and write
$$1\cdot v_1+(-1)\cdot v_2=0$$
but $1\ne0$ and $-1\ne0$, contradicting the hypothesis. Since $S$ is empty, its span is the zero subspace, and it's true that the zero vector can be uniquely written as a linear combination of the vectors in the empty set, namely as the empty linear combination. But this isn't very satisfying.

The problem is that the authors failed to require that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be *distinct* vectors in $S$, and from a quick glance at the book they do not seem to adopt a general notational convention that would implicitly require it. (I'm looking at the 13th printing of the 4th edition. I'm unable to find an up to date errata sheet for this edition online.)

If we require distinctness, then the hypothesis amounts to the fact that $S$ is **linearly independent**, which the authors define (correctly) in the section following the exercise. In this case we can make a uniqueness claim, using the following definition (adapted from Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra*, 3rd edition, p.45):

> A nonzero vector $v\in V$ has an **essentially unique** representation over a subset $S$ of $V$ if, up to order of terms, there is one and only one way to express $v$ as a linear combination
> $$v=a_1s_1+\cdots+a_ns_n$$
> where the $s_i$'s are distinct vectors in $S$ and the coefficients $a_i$ are nonzero. More explicitly, $v\ne 0$ has an essentially unique representation over $S$ if $v\in\mathrm{span}(S)$ and if whenever
> $$v=a_1s_1+\cdots+a_ns_n\qquad\text{and}\qquad v=b_1t_1+\cdots+b_mt_m$$
> where the $s_i$'s are distinct in $S$, the $t_i$'s are distinct in $S$, and all coefficients are nonzero, then $m=n$ and after a reindexing if necessary, we have $a_i=b_i$ and $s_i=t_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

The result is that:

> If $S$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, then every nonzero vector $v\in\mathrm{span}(S)$ has an essentially unique representation over $S$.

Indeed, if
$$0\ne v=a_1s_1+\cdots+a_ns_n=b_1t_1+\cdots+b_m t_m$$
where the $s_i$'s are distinct in $S$, the $t_i$'s are distinct in $S$, and all coefficients are nonzero, then after reindexing if necessary and subtracting and regrouping, we can write
$$\begin{align*}
0&=(a_1-b_1)s_1+\cdots+(a_k-b_k)s_k\\
&\quad+a_{k+1}s_{k+1}+\cdots+a_ns_n\\
&\quad-b_{k+1}t_{k+1}-\cdots-b_mt_m
\end{align*}$$
where all the vectors on the right are distinct in $S$. It follows from linear independence of $S$ that we must have $n=m=k$ and $a_i=b_i$ and $s_i=t_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

See my other answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4766434/129912) for more information about this type of issue.